# Injective, Surjective functions help

Tags: functions

f : N → N
I am seriously struggling with finding examples of functions f : N → N for:
f is neither injective nor surjective, 
f is injective but not surjective,
f is surjective but not injective,
f is surjective and injective

any help would be greatly aprreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following are easy, so I'll leave them to you.

1. Injective but not surjective. (Hint: what is the most important function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$?)
2. Neither injective nor surjective. (Hint: what is the simplest function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$?)

For surjective but not injective, define $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by $f(n) = \mathrm{max}(0,n-1)$.